# SELinux on Raspberry Pi 3 running CentOS 7

Tags: pi-3, linux, security

**Issue**

I'm running CentOS 7 on a Raspberry Pi 3 (image here: http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/isos/armhfp/CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-Minimal-1602-RaspberryPi3.img.xz). I'm attempting to enable SELinux on the Pi. After installing the necessary packages, changing the parameter `SELINUX=disabled` to `SELINUX=permissive`, and running:

```
touch /.autorelabel
reboot
```

all as the root user, I'm still faced with the following output after reboot:

```
$ getenforce
Disabled
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

**Troubleshooting**

I've installed the following packages:

```
policycoreutils 
policycoreutils-python 
selinux-policy 
selinux-policy-targeted 
libselinux-utils 
setroubleshoot-server 
setools 
setools-console
```

The current content of `/etc/selinux/config`:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

I know that bootloaders such as grub sometimes disable SELinux in their config files during boot but I checked the native raspberry pi boot configs (`/boot/config.txt` and `/boot/cmdline.txt`) and there doesn't seem to be anything that would disable SELinux in those either.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: [Guide SELinux {Get/Install/Setup}](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=16738) This page will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELinux requires kernel support, and the default Raspberry Pi kernel does not include it.  You can check the configuration this way:

```
sudo modprobe configs
sudo gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep SELINUX
```

You'll get nothing with the pi's stock kernel.  By contrast, here's the output using the `defconfig` from a vanilla 4.2.1 source:

```
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=1
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=1
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX is not set
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
```

So, you have to configure and build your own kernel.  If you are comfortable with that and it seems worthwhile, [here's the official Pi kernel source tree](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).

I recommend cross-compiling it as it will probably take at least an hour (or two...) even on the 3 -- I don't know.  If you look up a level in that github repo there is a cross-compiler there under "tools", but, for the version used on the Pi 2/3 you can also use the arm-linux-gnueabi cross-compiler that is stock on most current linux distros (CentOS has a lot less available than most though, so if you use that elsewhere you may have to install a fedora or similar rpm from rpmfind).

## Beware

This is no guarantee that it will actually work on the Pi (just a pretty good bet), so you may want to search around to see if anyone has actually confirmed using it.